# How Can I Run A Test on Cypress, and Simultaneously Use The Cypress Inspector Tool To Build Other Tests?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I've got Cypress open running an `e2e` test that takes about 4 minutes. I've used the command in the `CLI` `npx cypress open`.

Whilst that is open and running, I would like to use the inspector tool
from Cypress to build another test.

Whilst building `e2e` tests, the gui does not allow for me to open another browser and start.

What would be a viable and repeatable option to run one test, whilst using the gui to build out another test with the inspector tool components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use `npx cypress open` a second time and have 2 instances of cypress working, one for the inspector tool and one for testing in the background.